# Observers and Asynchrony in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I follewed the guide on [the ember.js homepage](http://www.emberjs.com) and found that code at [this section](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/#toc_observers-and-asynchrony):

```
Person.reopen({
  lastNameChanged: function() {
    // The observer depends on lastName and so does fullName. Because observers
    // are synchronous, when this function is called the value of fullName is
    // not updated yet so this will log the old value of fullName
    console.log(this.get('fullName'));
  }.observes('lastName')
});
```

According to the comments the function `lastNameChanged` should output an old version of the fullName property. But when I ran my slightly modifed code I got the new version of the property:

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,

    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName'),
});

Person.reopen({
    lastNameChanged: function() {
        console.log('lastName changed. Name is now: ' + this.get('fullName'));
    }.observes('lastName')
})

max = Person.create({
    firstName: 'Max',
    lastName: 'Lehmann',
});

max.set('lastName', 'Mustermann');
console.log(max.get('fullName'));
```

I know that the guide is based on an older version of Emberjs (I suppose 1.3). I tested the code with the current version of Ember (1.6.1). Does the new version explain the change in that behaviour?

Comment: Try observesBefore('lastName') instead of observes('lastName')

Comment: Great, thank you! Now it shows me the name before updating it. Do you know whether this was caused by the newer version of Ember?

Comment: I dont really know what the previous version did. Observers are fired after a a value is changed. fullname is a computed property and only gets executed when you try to access it. When you access it, inside the obeserver, lastname is already changed hence fullname will give the new value. To get the previous value we use the before observer.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Please answer the question next time so I can mark this thread as solved.

Comment: This behaviour is true for all versions since 1.0.0. I have not tested earlier versions.

Comment: But this would mean that there is an error in the documentation/guides on the the official ember website...

Comment: You might wanna file a bug at their github page.

Comment: Ok, I did it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observers are fired after a a value is changed. fullname is a computed property and only gets executed when you try to access it. When you access it, inside the obeserver, lastname is already changed hence fullname will give the new value. To get the previous value we use the before observer.

Use `observesBefore('lastName')` instead of `observes('lastName')`